# Objective C: array of class object as property

Tags: objective-c, arrays, class, properties

Is it possible in an Objective-C class to store an array of instances of another class as a property?

Simple example: I have a class called "Classroom" and a class called "Students".

```
@interface Student
    @property int m_id;
@end
```

...

```
@interface Classroom
    @property Student *m_students[20]; // this causes a compilation error: property cannot have an array or function type 'Student *[20]'
@end
```

How can I do the equivalent of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` instead:

```
@interface Classroom
    @property NSMutableArray *m_students; // this causes a compilation error.
@end
```

Then in your implementation:

```
Student *student = [[Student alloc] init];
[self.m_students addObject:student];
```

`NSArray` (and it's subclass `NSMutableArray`) can contain any Objective-C object. And you can even mix them in the same array.

Comment: Thanks! So if I want 20 students in my array, should this be done 20 times?

Comment: Yes you have to do 20 times

Comment: offcourse using a loop/recursion (: and inherit both of the class from NSObject